# sql get top n row based for each unique entry

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table like so

| S.No | col1 | query | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | entry1 | query1 | 10 |
| 2 | entry1 | query2 | 2 |
| 3 | entry1 | query3 | 100 |
| 4 | entry2 | query4 | 0 |
| 5 | entry2 | query5 | 50 |
| 6 | entry2 | query6 | 20 |

I want to get the top 2 rows based on score for each unique entry. Meaning I need

| col1 | query | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| entry1 | query3 | 100 |
| entry1 | query1 | 10 |
| entry2 | query5 | 50 |
| entry2 | query6 | 20 |

My query right now is

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    select col1, query, score, row_number() over(partition by col1 order by score desc) as rn 
    FROM table)
where rn<=2;
```

The problem is i'm also getting an extra column `rn`. Yes i know that removing `select *` would solve the issue but is there a cleaner way?

| col1 | query | score | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| entry1 | query3 | 100 | 1 |
| entry1 | query1 | 10 | 2 |
| entry2 | query5 | 50 | 1 |
| entry2 | query6 | 20 | 2 |

How do i achieve this without the `rn` column?

Sorry if this question has been asked before but i couldn't figure out the keywords to find it.

I'm using AWS Athena since my data is in S3.

Comment: Shouldn't your where clause be ` rn <= 2`instead of ` rn < 2`?

Comment: Yes! I've updated it

Answer (score 0):

No, currently there is no way to exclude column(s) from a table without specifying all the columns. This is not a part of standard SQL, AFAIK, and Presto/Trino does not implement it. So you need to specify all needed colums in the final `SELECT`:

```sql
select col1, query, score
from ...
```

Useful links:

- [`SELECT` Presto docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html)

Comment: If there a way to achieve what i'm trying using a different query? A query which doesn't make me use nested queries?

Comment: @Belphegor21 not, to my knowledge there is not.